# what are other approaches instead of using collect() in spark scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

My piece of scala code looks like,

```
val orgIncInactive = orgIncLatest.filter("(LD_TMST != '' and LD_TMST is not   null)").select("ORG_ID").rdd

orgIncInactive.collect.foreach(p => DenormalizedTablesMethodsUtil.hbaseTablePurge(p(0).toString, tableName, connection))
```

Is there any way that I can avoid using collect() here?
I tried various possibilities but I am ending up with Serializable errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are trying to do, and what is ultimately causing the serialization error. It looks like you are trying to pass some kind of database connection into the anonymous function. That's generally going to fail for a couple of reasons. Even if you made the connection object itself serializable -- say by sub-classing the object and implementing `Serializable` -- database connections are not something you can share between the driver and the executors.

Instead, what you need to do is to create the connection object on each of the executors, and then use the local connection object instead of one defined in the driver. There are a couple of ways to accomplish this.

One is to use `mapPartitions`, which allows you to instantiate objects locally before the logic is run. See **[here](http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com/2015/11/mappartition-example.html)** for more on this.

Another possibility is to create a singleton object that on initialization sets a connection object to `null` or `None`. Then, you would define a method in the object like "getConnection" that checks whether the connection has been initialized. If not, it initializes the connection. Then either way it returns the valid connection.

I use the second approach more than the first, because it limits initialization to only once per executor instead of forcing it to happen once per partition.